# using Python reduce over a list of pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce, accumulator

I'm trying to pair together a bunch of elements in a list to create a final object, in a way that's analogous to making a sum of objects.  I'm trying to use a simple variation on `reduce` where you consider a list of pairs rather than a flat list to do this.  I want to do something along the lines of:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, nums)
```

except I'd like to add additional information to the sum that is specific to each element in the list of numbers `nums`. For example for each pair (a,b) in the list, run the sum as (a+b):

```
nums = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 10)]
reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+x[1]) + (y[0]+y[1]), nums)
```

This does not work:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+x[1]) + (y[0]+y[1]), nums)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

Why does it not work? I know I can encode `nums` as a flat list - that is not the point - I just want to be able to create a reduce operation that can iterate over a list of pairs, or over two lists of the same length simultaneously and pool information from both lists.  thanks.

Comment: Do you want the result of the reduce to be a tuple?

Comment: Do you have to use reduce? I prefer the simple 
    sum(x[0] + x[1] for x in nums)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the lambda you passed to `reduce`:

```
f = lambda x, y: (x[0]+x[1]) + (y[0]+y[1])
```

The value returned by `f` will be passed as a parameter to another invocation of `f`. But while `f` expects its parameters to be pairs, the value it returns is an `int`. You need to make this function return a pair as well. For example, this would sum up the left and right sides separately:

```
>>> nums = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 10)]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), nums)
(6, 15)
```

Another thing you can do is treat the accumulated value differently from the list elements: You can make the accumulated value an `int`, while the list elements are pairs. If you do this, you must pass the `initializer` argument to `reduce`, so that the accumulator is initialized correctly to an `int`:

```
>>> nums = [(1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 10)]
>>> reduce(lambda acc, y: acc + y[0] + y[1], nums, 0)
21
```

Comment: Is there a way to just get an iterator from reduce over the pairs? Something analogous to `enumerate(mylist)` for lists, where it returns not only the current element but also its position in the list. Can the `lambda` in `reduce` get access to the number of the pair being used in the above example?

Comment: @user248237 You can use `enumerate(mylist)` as the input to `reduce`.